# How do we get posters to give more specific use cases?

Tags: discussion

Many questions on this site don't provide much information about the use-case or context surrounding their product. They ask for universal patterns on, say, arranging kinds of data, or on how to handle scrolling and pagination, without giving any kind of data on how the product is going to be used or who is going to use it.

Typically, I try to request more info using question comments. But is there any way we can get people to post better, more pointed questions right from the off?